# How to stop inline ckeditor div resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I have a `div` with contenteditable set to true and I am making editable with an inline CKEditor instance.

As I type in the `div`, it naturally grows in the vertical direction as the text fills up or when I press return.

If I set the height and max-height CSS of the editor `div` then, the `div` itself doesn't grow BUT the editor carries on letting me enter text all the way down the page (it breaks out of the div).

What I want to be able to do is lock the inline editor area to, say, `100px` in height and, ideally, not allow any more lines to be inserted.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: can you remove quote and try height : '200'  => height : 200 in your initialization?

Comment: Tried that - still no joy.  I think it may be simply that CKEditor just can't do it in Inline mode ?

Comment: add removePlugins: 'resize', and try

Comment: as per the blog http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKE4-autogrow-min-height-problem-HELP below works  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  height: 500
});

Comment: Tried all above suggestions.  Still doesn't work.  It does specify on the CK docs that resizing only works on Classic mode and not Inline.  Thing is, I need Inline as I have a series of editor boxes and I only want to toolbar to appear when I click in them to edit (and then dissapear when I click somewhere else).

Comment: If the provider documents itself it is specified that it will not work on inline, its waste of time to spend on it. Think about alternate ways or alternate editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around I found the answer and it was simple.  Just apply a height and overflow-y:auto to the css of the containing div.  Works a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

Configure height and turn off auto grow:

```
config.autoGrow_onStartup = false,
config.resize_enabled = false,
config.height = '500px';
```

Comment: Tried that but it appears that "inline" mode is not supporting the parameters (only "classic" mode i think).  Trouble is, I need inline mode.

Here is the code snippet I am using to initialise - does it look correct ?

    CKEDITOR.inline( 'editorbox',{ resize_enabled : false, autoGrow_onStartup : false, height : '200' } );

Answer (score 0):

You have to set hight and width during intializing the ckeditor

```
config.height = 500;        // 500 pixels high.
config.height = '25em';     // CSS unit (em).
```

To Disable resizing

```
config.resize_enabled = false;
```

Reference: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size

Comment: I tried that but it would appear the the "inline" editor mode I am using (and need to use) doesn't support the height property.

Comment: try @Daimos answer config.autoGrow_onStartup = false,

Comment: Add config.autoGrow_onStartup = false, before setting config.height?